# Launching an intent from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

Hi this is my first question on stackoverflow and I'm a beginner on Android programming. I've looked through numerous webpages but can't seem to find my solution. What I'm trying to do is launch a new activity when a button is pressed after 5 seconds with a BroadcastReceiver. This activity will have a new UI with graphics and sounds (eventually). I got the BroadcastReceiver to work but the program crashes when it tries to launch the new intent. What am I doing wrong?

The method in my MainActivity class:

```
public void setAlarm(){     
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 5 * 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

My BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, ShakeActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent1); 
        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shakecounter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.shakecounter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.shakecounter.ShakeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_shake" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.shakecounter.MyBroadcastReceiver">
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when You are starting from inside a Receiver:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, ShakeActivity.class);
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent1);
```

If there is another problem, You should post the logcat.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, ShakeActivity.class);
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
Intent iAlarm = new Intent( mcontext1, Alertdialogclass.class ); 
iAlarm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND); 
iAlarm.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
mcontext1.startActivity(iAlarm);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!